# How to wait for an http request to be completed ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, ionic-framework, request

I'm new on Stack Overflow so I hope I'll find someone able to solve my problem.

There's what's going on : I'm currently creating an app with ionic and I need to execute a few HTTP request, because I need data from GoogleMaps. Until then I was working with very few waypoints so I could do just one request, but now, and because we're limited, I have to execute many of them.

The problem is, I try to fill a matrix with distances between places, but javascript I asynchronous and thus it doen't work... Here is a piece of my code just for you to understand, I try do create a for loop in order to fill my matrix and I'd like to find a way to force my script to wait for the answer of each request befor continuing.

```js
for ( this.k = 0; this.k < this.adresses_split.length - 1; this.k ++){
        this.url = this.url1 + this.adresses_split[this.k] + this.url2 + this.phraseCl  + this.url3
        console.log(this.url)
          
        this.httpB.get(this.url,{},{}).then(data =>{
        
          for ( this.i = 1; this.i < 4; this.i++ ){
            
            
            for(this.j = this.i + 1 + 3*this.k ; this.j< this.clients.length + 1; this.j++ ){
              this.distances.push(this.i- 1 + 3*this.k);
              this.distances.push(this.j - 1);
              this.distances.push(data.data.split('elements')[this.i].split('duration')[this.j].split('value" : ')[1].split(' ')[0])
              
            }
            
          } 

          
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error.status);
          this.teste=error.error; // error message as string
          console.log(error.headers);
          
        });

      }
```

httpB stands for HTTP Bis because I had an other one created but this is a basic http request.

If I'm not clear just tell me, thanks for your help !

Comment: you're clearly looking for `Promise.all([]).then()`. It will enter into the `then` callback only when all the promises (in this case, the http calls) are completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect all the `Promise` objects in an Array and then use `Promise.all(theCollection).then(()=>{})`.

You didn't post your whole code here... so I am taking some guesses. The following code will give you some idea on how to fix the problem.

```
var promises = [];
for (this.k = 0; this.k < this.adresses_split.length - 1; this.k ++){
    this.url = this.url1 + this.adresses_split[this.k] + this.url2 + this.phraseCl  + this.url3
    console.log(this.url)

    promises.push(
        this.httpB.get(this.url,{},{}).then(data =>{
            for ( this.i = 1; this.i < 4; this.i++ ){
                for(this.j = this.i + 1 + 3*this.k ; this.j< this.clients.length + 1; this.j++ ){
                    this.distances.push(this.i- 1 + 3*this.k);
                    this.distances.push(this.j - 1);
                    this.distances.push(data.data.split('elements')[this.i].split('duration')[this.j].split('value" : ')[1].split(' ')[0]);
                }
            } 
        }).catch(error => {
              console.log(error.status);
              this.teste=error.error; // error message as string
              console.log(error.headers);
        })
    );

}

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    ... do you stuff...
}
```

**Update:** In response to your comment - if you like to see and/or process the results of all of the `get` requests at once, change the code as follows:

```
var promises = [];
for (this.k = 0; this.k < this.adresses_split.length - 1; this.k ++){
    this.url = this.url1 + this.adresses_split[this.k] + this.url2 + this.phraseCl  + this.url3
    console.log(this.url)
    promises.push(this.httpB.get(this.url,{},{})
        .then(data => data)
        .catch(error => {
              console.log(error.status);
              this.teste=error.error; // error message as string
              console.log(error.headers);
        })
    );    
}

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    for(let r = 0; r < results.length; r++){
        let data = results[r];

        for(this.i=1; this.i < 4; this.i++){
            for(this.j = this.i + 1 + 3*this.k ; this.j< this.clients.length + 1; this.j++ ){
                this.distances.push(this.i- 1 + 3*this.k);
                this.distances.push(this.j - 1);
                this.distances.push(data.data.split('elements')[this.i].split('duration')[this.j].split('value" : ')[1].split(' ')[0]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Note:** I didn't test the above code, so there can be some errors. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I have to admit I don't master promises but I'm going to give it a try and I'll tell you ! but thanks :)

Comment: For a reason I ignore they deleted my post where I was answering you... I said I didn't master promises and didn't succeed to display what HTTP requests usually send back... Could you just modify your script for it to display the result of the first request please ? Just for me tounderstand the structure. Thanks !

Comment: you're my heroe :*